# Invalid identifier, attribute in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT C1.CERT_ANNOUNCEMENT
FROM EMPLOYEE C1, TEACHER C1, TEACHER_CERT_INT C1, CERTIFICATION C1
ORDER BY EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME;
```

Write a query and save it as a view to create announcement text for all teachers in the database that have
obtained certifications. The attribute you create should be named as below and the string you create must look
exactly as in the solution for full credit. Order by last name then first name.
It is supposed to be named CERT_ANNOUNCEMENT but this is not an attribute in the ER DIAGRAM.

Don't know how to create it exactly because when I run this it say invalid identifier. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: If you want us to do your homework for you you need to post all the details of the assignment.  Otherwise you won't get "full credit" for our efforts :)

Comment: Though your teacher should be docked some points for telling you to write a view with an ORDER BY clause.  That's bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use unique alias for each table and use `on` clause to do joins and avoid full cartesian product, and also elaborate better your questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment asks you to create a view so you need to use the CREATE VIEW syntax.

The view uses data from several tables.  You need to use join conditions to ensure that records are linked meaningfully.  This usually means joining primary keys to foreign keys.

Give each table a unique alias to avoid compilation errors.

The view is supposed to show a message for all the teachers who have been awarded certificates.  You need to form this announcement by concatenating columns from the tables with boilerplate text.  Give this message a column alias of `cert_announcement`.

You not have posted any table structures so I have guessed what your tables' columns are called.  Likewise the actual text of the announcement.  So you need to figure out the precise details for yourself.  At least that way you'll have earned some of the marks you'll get.

```
create or replace view full_credit_please as 
    select 'Teacher '
           ||emp.emp_fname||' '||emp.emp_lname
           ||' was awarded '||cert.certifcate_name
           ||' on '|| to_char(cert.award_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
           as cert_announcement
    from employee emp
         join teacher tch
              on tch.emp_id = emp.emp_id
         join teacher_cert_int tc
              on tc.tch_id = tch.tch_id
         join certification cert
              on cert.cert_id = tc.cert_id
    order by emp.emp_lname, emp.emp_fname;
```